# Нужна помощь с data-color button`а

Tags: javascript

нужен скрипт который будет задавать data-color button-а при клике заднему фону Navbar`а  на чистом js, объясните пож-ста,ибо в деле новичок,и не совсем понимаю,спасибо за помощь)

```css
.btn-violet {
  background-color: #563d7c;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(24, 18, 18);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Change Backgroud</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-color="#007bff">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-color="#28a745">Success</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-color="#dc3545">Danger</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-violet" data-color="#563d7c">Violet</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-color="#ffc107">Warning</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-color="#17a2b8">Info</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-color="#343a40">Dark</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляем следующий код в JS-файл:

```js
document.querySelector('.container').onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    document.querySelector('nav').style.backgroundColor = e.target.getAttribute('data-color');
  }
}
```

```css
.btn-violet {
  background-color: #563d7c;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(24, 18, 18);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Change Backgroud</h1>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-color="#007bff">Primary</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-color="#28a745">Success</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-color="#dc3545">Danger</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-violet" data-color="#563d7c">Violet</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-color="#ffc107">Warning</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-color="#17a2b8">Info</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-color="#343a40">Dark</button>
</div>
```

Comment: А что за функция(e)? просто рандомное название функции?

Comment: @Александр Нет, не рандомное. Такая запись называется "анонимной функцией". Если не нужно вызывать функцию где-то ещё, то не стоит создавать отдельную именованную.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,очень выручали,дай Бог Вам крепкого здоровичка)